# PIC MCU wont accept external oscillator

Tags: pic, oscillator

I have been trying to use a [PIC16F684](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41202C.pdf) with an external oscillator. I tried a few, changed capacitors, added series resistor - nothing.

Right now I have a [10 MHz crystal](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/57345.pdf) connected with 30 pF capacitors and a 60 ohm series resistor as per figure 3-3 from the PIC's datasheet (page 23.) I have also tried without a series resistor.

I use mikroC to test it by blinking an LED:

```
void main() {
    CMCON0 = 0x07;
    TRISC = 2;
    while(1)
    {
        RC5_bit = 1;
        Delay_ms(500);
        RC5_bit = 0;
        Delay_ms(500);
    } }
```

This only works if I allow the fail-safe clock monitor to switch over to the internal oscillator (I.E. LED blinks based on internal oscillator.)
If I have not selected this option then the LED never blinks.

In the current configuration, I used single two-pin 10 MHz oscillators, three 10 pF capacitors for each oscillator's pin.

The code is uploaded via the [K150 programmer](https://hobbycomponents.com/pic/179-pic-k150-icsp-programmer).

Previous tries were made with 16 MHz and 22 pF.

Here are my set fuses:

[image]

Here is my system:

[image]

The LED legs are not touching anything else.

Comment: You keep saying "oscillator", but I think you mean "crystal". Please clarify. What exactly are the part(s) you're using?

Comment: Please define what exactly you bought and how you connected it and how yoi set the config/fuse/etc settings. Crystal oscillators are not crystals and crystals are oscillators.

Comment: Those are crystals - i put link on wrong words. I am using very bare fuses - only HS is set.

Comment: The 60 ohm is the internal ESR of the crystal and largely unrelated to any series resistance you have added. When you say you have "tried without series resistor", what exactly do you mean i.e. did you remove it and leave it open circuit. Post a circuit image to avoid confusion please. How did you decide on the loading capacitance. There's nothing in the data sheet that tells you the value.

Comment: The datasheet states 'Load Capacitance (CL): 10pF to 75pF or Series'. Yes, I did try with and without 60 Ohm. I am starting to think, maybe the PIC is faulty?

Comment: @RiDi That is what the datasheet says. But that range is not for your specific crystal. Your crystal was manufactured with a specific load capacitance.

Comment: The vendor that i bought from states 30 pF in its webpage for the product, that is why I added 30 pF.

Comment: @RiDi You need to tell which exact crystal model you bought. And, if a crystal says 30pF load, it does not mean you add 30pF to both crystal pins.

Comment: Okay, i did check again - my vendor stated its 16-30 pF. This is the product (identical code): https://www.tme.com/us/en-us/details/4.00m-hc49-s/tht-quartz-crystals/yic/

Comment: @RiDi That link goes to a 4 MHz 20pF crystal. You cannot have a range for a crystal, any crystal you will buy has a specific CL it is tuned to operate, not a range.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to build a sensitive crystal oscillator on a breadboard.

You also have no bypass caps at all on the power supply.

I would not expect it to work.

You have long jumper wires and the wiring of the breadboard itself is also a problem. This includes making bad contact, the breadboard wires having stray capacitance between them and stray inductance.

Your crystal is unknown. You posted a datasheet for a series of crystals with wide range of parameters, but the crystals you bought are available has a specific set of those parameters.

You cannot determine what is the correct amount of load capacitance for your crystal, you only see from the datasheet you can buy them with CL range of 10pF to 75pF or no load capacitance for the series resonance model.

One part of the problem might be that you have selected the HS oscillator for the project, but have not programmed the CONFIG bits to the Configuration Word register to actually make the PIC to go into HS oscillator mode. A generic program upload might not reprogram the CONFIG word for safety reasons, as programming it incorrectly may lock you out of the MCU, so it can't be reprogrammed or it won't run and you can't change the settings easily.

Comment: Just a side note as well: breadboards have a tendency to attenuate high frequencies because of their extremely small stray capacitance.

Comment: @Colin Insertion loss itself is usually a non-issue when the wiring length is under a few centimeters. Usually crosstalks, phase shifts, ground bounces, overshoots from breadboard parasitics are the real problems, especially for anything with a feedback loop.

Answer (score 1):

A few revisions of PIC16F684 data sheets shows crystal oscillator configuration on different pages: **FIGURE 3-3: QUARTZ CRYSTAL OPERATION (LP, XT OR HS MODE)** shows how an AT-cut crystal is connected to two pins to form an oscillator.

**\$R_S, C_1, C_2\$** are external components that you attach to **OSC1/CLKIN** and **OSC2/CLKOUT** pins. Note that the common ground connection of \$C_1, C_2\$ should be a short path to 16F684 \$V_{SS}\$ pin. \$R_F\$ is an internal bias resistor, and *should not* be added externally.

When operating properly, a DC voltage measured with a high-impedance voltmeter should show about one-half of \$V_{DD}\$ on the **OSC2/CLKOUT** pin. A X10-attenuator oscilloscope probe on **OSC2/CLKOUT** pin should show some 10MHz oscillations.

OP's *fail-safe* start-up configuration suggests that the crystal oscillator is not oscillating.
My personal experience with 16F684 DIP package on a breadboard, in HS crystal operation gave no trouble. No Rs was used while debugging circuits. In some cases, inherent breadboard capacitance alone was enough to allow oscillations (C1, C2 = 0pf). Since breadboard stray capacitance is significant, slightly smaller capacitance values might be advised. On a breadboard, flying leads from the grounded sides of C1, C2 should bridge directly to Vss.

And don't forget the most important capacitor of all: the one directly between \$V_{DD}, V_{SS}\$ pins of the 16F684.

Crystal oscillators require much more time to stabilize than RC oscillators. Turning on **Power-up timer** in the configuration word might help.

---

A PIC16F684 was programmed:

- _HS_OSC
- _PWRTE_ON
- _BOD_OFF
- _MCLRE_OFF

A 10MHz HC-49 crystal was attached to OSC1/OSC2, along with two oscilloscope probes, set to X10 attenuator (10M resistance, perhaps 10pf each). Oscilloscope probe capacitance was enough to start oscillations:
[image: Two channel oscilloscope screen PIC16F684]

OSC1/CLKin slightly exceeded supply voltage, suggesting robust oscillations. Note that OSC2/CLKout is roughly half-Vdd(+4.76V). OSC1 average voltage is roughly half-Vdd too.
[image: oscillating!]

Comment: I have tested with no CAPs - no result. Then I measured voltages on OSC2 was 50 mV, OSC1 was 240 mV (with multimeter). My oscilloscope is 5Mhz so I added another 4 Mhz crystal and put probe on OSC2 (GND to GND) - i did not notice anything. What should I expect to see? A sin wave of 4Mhz? (all this was done with power up timer ON).

I use 5V lab voltage source.

Comment: With DC voltages that low on OSC1, OSC2, it's not going to oscillate. Try pulling out ALL the components attached to OSC1, OSC2...and re-measure. If voltage is *still not close* to half-Vdd, then something's faulty - either a bad 16F684, bad breadboard, or your CONFIG word is not putting OSC1, OSC2 pins into HS mode. Of course, its not going to oscillate with all components pulled out, but this test will eliminate possible faulty capacitors.

Comment: I tested again - OSC2 has 38mV, OSC1 has 220mV. I tested new 16F684 - 130 and 180mV. I should look for another programmer. This gave me problems with other PICs (refused to upload by giving me some made up errors)

Comment: I ordered PICKIT, will see what happens.